# fazer append de string e looping 'for'

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def conf_dir_exist(lines):
    temp = ''
    print(lines) #isso é uma tuple.
    for line_a in lines:
        for line_b in line_a:
            if(os.path.exists(line_b) != False):
                pass
            else:
                temp += ''.join(line_b + '; ')
                print('\n\tDirectory ' + str(line_a) + ' < ' + temp + '> not exist.')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    conf_dir_exist((['w:/', 'g:/', 'd:/', 'x:/', 'y:/'], ['c:/data', 'd:/data']))
```

tendo em vista que os diretórios: 'w:/', 'd:/ e 'd:/data ' não existem como diretórios como fazer append em uma string em outra durante o looping interno e exibir o resultado no fim do mesmo looping.

Answer (score 0):

Basta definires uma string para esse efeito no início, antes do looping:

```
def conf_dir_exist(lines):
    temp = ''
    print(lines) #isso e uma tuple.
    string_final = ''
    for line_a in lines:
        for line_b in line_a:
            if(os.path.exists(line_b) != False):
                pass
            else:
                temp += ''.join(line_b + '; ')
                string_final += '\n\tDirectory ' + str(line_a) + ' < ' + temp + '> not exist.'
    print(string_final)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    conf_dir_exist((['w:/', 'g:/', 'd:/', 'x:/', 'y:/'], ['c:/data', 'd:/data']))
```

Você também pode guardá-las em um array de strings para manipular como quiser depois:

```
log = []
log.append('my string')
```